# Variavel soma não pega o valor dentro do laço!

Tags: python, while

```
print ("Produto Numero 1")  
ValorDaMercadoria = float(input("Qual o valor da mercadoria? "))  

print("Produto 1",":",ValorDaMercadoria)  
NumeroDoProduto = 2  
ValorDaMercadoriaLaco = 1  

while ValorDaMercadoriaLaco != 0:  
    print ("Produto Numero",NumeroDoProduto)  
    ValorDaMercadoriaLaco = float(input("Qual o valor da mercadoria? "))  

    print("Produto",NumeroDoProduto,":",ValorDaMercadoriaLaco)  
    NumeroDoProduto = NumeroDoProduto + 1  
    SomaDosPrecosDasMercadorias = ValorDaMercadoria + ValorDaMercadoriaLaco  
print("Soma dos precos",SomaDosPrecosDasMercadorias)  
print ("Lojas Tabajara")
```

Aqui no meu código a soma esta pegando somente meu primeiro numero digitado e não esta pegando o valor que for digitado dentro do while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rennan, acontece que seu acumulador **SomaDosPrecosDasMercadorias** está recebendo o valor do produto, mas não mantém o valor anterior... Para manter os valores no acumulador, você pode utilizar do sinal **+=**

Uma possível correção seria a seguinte, deixei alguns comentários para facilitar a sua leitura do código:

```
#Acumulador de valores
SomaDosPrecosDasMercadorias = 0
#Número do produto
NumeroDoProduto = 1
#Preço informado no laço
ValorDaMercadoriaLaco = -1

while ValorDaMercadoriaLaco != 0:
    print ("Produto Numero",NumeroDoProduto)  
    ValorDaMercadoriaLaco = float(input("Qual o valor da mercadoria? "))  

    print("Produto",NumeroDoProduto,":",ValorDaMercadoriaLaco)

    #Soma o número do produto
    NumeroDoProduto += 1
    #Acumula o valor do produto
    SomaDosPrecosDasMercadorias += ValorDaMercadoriaLaco

print("Soma dos precos",SomaDosPrecosDasMercadorias)  
print ("Lojas Tabajara")
```

Comment: Tentei da forma que você me sugeriu porem não deu certo.   
SomaDosPrecosDasMercadorias = ValorDaMercadoria + ValorDaMercadoriaLaco
nessa linha de código acima o SomaDosPrecosDasMercadorias só esta armazenando o valor do ValorDaMercadoria, é não pega os valores digitados dentro no While.(ValorDaMercadoriaLaco).
por ultimo se eu tiver por exemplo x=x+1, não seria a mesma coisa que x+=1?

Comment: Renan, x +=1 é a mesma coisa que x = x + 1... Porém em seu exemplo, você não usa nenhum dos dois.

Comment: consegui resolver esse problema porem estou com outro. não estou usando funções no meu programa pq na resolução da questão não pode fazer com função. no final do algoritmo quando ele fizer o calculo como faço para ele manualmente voltar ao inicio e pedir novamente os valores dos produtos?

Comment: Se você não pode utilizar de funções, você terá de colocar praticamente todo o seu código dentro de um loop.